# How to handle 'missing key values' in CSV dictionary and working through Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, dictionary, data-analysis

I want to reject the records in pandas data frame where key values are missing and assigning only those records which are present in CSV. For example match only those 'Names' where 'prices' are mentioned.

```
'Names' 'price'
Ram      100
John     200
dan 
Mike     500
Capri
```

Comment: Not clear. Are you comparing an existing DataFrame to a separate csv?  An [mcve] would be usefull. Please also read [ask].

Comment: What values are "key"?

Comment: In the example. 'Key' is 'Names' and 'Price' is assigned to it. I need to keep only those records where 'price' are available. My dictionary is in CSV and am accessing my DF through Python.

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Despite multiple comments, this remains quite unclear...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.dropna()
```

It will drop the entire row of an empty value

To count the rows that have a NaN value do this:

```
df.shape[0] - df.dropna().shape[0] 
# 2
```

if your counting matches for a map you can do it like this:

```
dictionary= {'Ram':100,'John':200,'Mike':500}

len(df[df.Names.map(dictionary).fillna(0) ==0])                                                                                                                                     
# 2

len(df[df.Names.map(dictionary).fillna(0) >0])                                                                                                                                      
# 3
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to "reject" rows that don't have "key" values (but may have others, so aren't completely empty).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I also need to count the number of records I rejected from that column of my data frame which has missing dictionary value. Your thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Rahul i added that to my answer, i hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated. You accessed shape through Index. What if I want access through column name. I have more than 200 columns. So it will be easy to access by name. Any suggestion.

Comment: You can use it per column the same way, is that what you mean:  df['price'].shape[0] - df['price'].dropna().shape[0]

Comment: btw, if you enjoyed the answer, check out: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235  and welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: No. I have the record of 'names' with additional 200 columns in which few of the names, price is missing. I have to access my data frame through 'Name'. Secondly why you used '0' if I want to access through column name.

Comment: Any more suggestion ? I really need help now.

Comment: @Rahul, it just a convention i use, i can help further, let me think about it. Can you give me an example, i think i know what you mean,  but i need a better description so i can formulate a good answer

Comment: My df has 200 columns. One of the column is mapped to dictionary in csv which is  mapped in python df. I have 10k records and few of the particular column records in dictionary may not match the dictionary. So I need to reject those records. Besides that I also need to count the records which I had rejected. I hope if am clear ? may be you can give me some loop function which can read dictionary and rejects records by itself.

Comment: @Rahul A column is mapped to a dictionary in a CSV file which is mapped to a (the same?) DataFrame?

Comment: any suggestions ?

Comment: dropna didnt worked out. It didnt save any record. I can see only column headers.My python is connected to database. When i wanted to export into CSV after passing dropna. It shows empty dataframe.

Comment: I think we should move this to chat to discuss further

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/204513/how-to-handle-missing-key-values-in-csv-dictionary?tab=general